# How to create the following list structure in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a list with following structure in sharepoint 2010. 
[image]

Is it possible to create like this?
You may say that enter values by leaving title as blank. But here `Title` Filed should be required field. 
If any one help me to do in programatically(C# code) I would feel great.

Comment: 1. enter proper title to all the products and we have grouping option to show your list item exactly same as above table. just groung by "title" .

Answer (score 0):

1. enter proper title to all the products and we have grouping option to show your list item exactly same as above table. Just group by "title" .
2. Better keep swap the display name of the "Title" and "Product" field, so that the Product will have any product name and the title is not required field now so you can leave as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the "`Title`" column a required field, then you must add value for it when adding an item.